# mui-rte MUIRichTextEditor how to place a picture and text in one line

Tags: javascript

Hello MUIRichTextEditor how to place a picture and text in one line

```
import MUIRichTextEditor from "mui-rte";
 <MUIRichTextEditor
                label="Type something here..."
                classes={cl}
                defaultValue={content}
            />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use css display flex , but this metod do

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).